# Mysqli prepared statements error?

Tags: php, mysqli

I've ran into this error with prepared statements, I've just started with prepared statements so go easy on me please, Heres the error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\wamp\www\darkhorizons\login.php on line 31

Heres my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(isset($username) && isset($password)) {

   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","phplogin") or die("Couldnt connect!");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_errno();
        exit();
    }

    if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =? AND password      =? LIMIT 1")){
    $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $stmt -> execute();

    $stmt -> bind_result($result);
    $stmt -> fetch();



    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

} else {
    die("Please enter a username and password!");
}

if($numrows == 1){

    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true ;

    $query = "SELECT adminflag FROM users WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['username']}' LIMIT 1;";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

    if ($numrows2 == 1) {
        $_SESSION['isadmin'] = true;
    }

    header("Location: {$pageLoc}");
    exit(); //It's good to use exit or die (same thing) AFTER using header to redirect

} else {


}

    }
    }
```

As a side note, Please ignore any mistakes in the code below the prepared statement, im redoing my login script that ive been using to learn.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - plus, form elements named, no typos? `session_start();` *etc. etc. etc.*

Comment: so for bind_result the number of params should be equal to the column number selected in SELECT Query

Comment: @SaurabhSinha Could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: Dumb question, have you tried modfying the query so that it's `= ?` instead of `=?` ?  I'm not sure how fussy mysqli is on syntax.

Comment: The manual on [bind_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) explains it. You were looking for `get_result()` and `fetch_array()` rather. (And yes, it's your own fault for picking Mysqli over PDO.)

Comment: if you write SELECT col1, col2 then bind_result($col1, $col2) but When you write SELECT * bind_result whould have number of parameters = number of columns in the TABLE. Sorry for my english

Comment: @Powerlord `= ?` and `=?` is fine. Yet `= '?'` is not. Just a quick FYI ;)

Comment: Please refer http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: @TaylorStevens you are also mixing OO and procedural style, that's not a good idea

Comment: @meda Well currently i was following a tutorial on the basics of prepared statements and thats what was taught so.. Guess i hould find  a better source lol

Comment: @TaylorStevens If you have that link, do share it so we can inspect it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

Comment: It's probably the `*` in `SELECT * FROM users` that's doing you in. You may have more than two columns in your table. Try selecting one column instead. The tutorial is selecting an actual column. `SELECT priv FROM testUsers` instead of "all".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through your code you didn't really need to query you DB twice, you should read the `adminflag` in that same select.

`SELECT *` is never a good idea always select specific fields.

And I also noticed you are using two differnt style, I suggest you to stick to the Object oriented approach.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['username'] , $_POST['password'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","phplogin");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT adminflag FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();
        $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
        printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", $numrows );

    if($numrows == 1){
        $stmt->bind_result($admin_flag);
        $stmt->fetch();
        session_start();
        if ($admin_flag== 1) {
            $_SESSION['isadmin'] = true;
        }
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true ;
        header("Location: {$pageLoc}");
    }else{
        echo 'user not found';
    }

}
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
}else{
    echo 'required field missing';
}
?>
```

Comment: I queried it twice because it will log in a user, but it checks for the admin flag, if the admin flag in the DB is 1 it will add to the users session ['isadmin'] allowing the admin to add news to the news system etc

Comment: @TaylorStevens I dont think you see what I am trying to point out, since it is the same table you are querying you can check if the record exist and if it does then check the admin flag.

Comment: Oh god, Im sorry i didnt pay much attention, was just going over it and saw, my bad

Comment: @TaylorStevens sure, you might have to adjust this line `if ($admin_flag== <ADMIN_VALUE_HERE>)`

Comment: The code is fine thanks, One problem though is i added a Die() after the else and when i press my login button the script just dies?

Comment: @TaylorStevens that means you put it in the wrong place `...$mysqli->close();}else{ die();}` check my edit please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58988/discussion-between-taylor-stevens-and-meda).

Comment: Dear researchers: DO NOT USE THIS ANSWER in your project.  Storing/Checking raw passwords is **NEVER** acceptable practice in any application.  Look else where for guidance on Stack Overflow.